# Syntax error in SaltStack state file

Tags: salt-stack

I am newbie with SaltStack. I have an error in one of my first state files.

The state file is:

```
openvpn:
  pkg.installed: []
  /etc/openvpn:
    file.recurse:
      - source: salt://myvpn/openvpn-files
  service.running: []
```

And the error: `State 'openvpn' in SLS u'myvpn' is not formed as a list`

Could you say me where is the fail?

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. It can't define a state inside other state (`/etc/openvpn:` inside `openvpn:`)

I've fixed this way:

```
openvpn:
  pkg.installed: []
  file.recurse:
    - name: /etc/openvpn
    - source: salt://myvpn/openvpn-files
  service.running: []
```